# Application with tab bar and navigation bar in all controllers

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a problem with adding tab bar to all the controllers in the screen, it's only shown in the controllers that is directly connected to the tab bar. How can I show It in all screens?

[image: This is my current main storyboard]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, my problem was I didn't add navigation controller for each tab bar item, I made only one navigation controller that's why the tab bar didn't appear.
The right sequence is:

**TabBarItem1 ->  NavController1 -> ViewController1 -> ViewController2**

**TabBarItem2 ->  NavController2 -> ViewController1 -> ViewController2**